# Instantly updating a image view on a activity from a fragment (sharing same screen)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a screen split into two halfs

the top one holds the profile data with profile pic and is static, the bottom half is fragments that are navigated through.  One of those fragments edits the details of the profile.  Now i like to make things hard for myself, so what i want is when the user presses "update", the information is changed at the top instanstly.  How on earth do i do that.  When the update is pressed..behind the scences the photo info goes through php to phpadmin and a string  of the photo path is uploaded ready for retrivel and the bit map is supposed to update the image view.
I was able to update the profile pic on the fragment with picasso when it was one complete fragment so i knwo that set up works..  Long story short how do i update an Image view which shares a screen but not activities or fragment layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like a user's interaction with a fragment to result in the update of a UI element in that fragment's parent activity.

The short answer is that while it is possible, the fragment should not update the UI element in the Activity directly. This is what is commonly known as "lack of separation of concerns", or in the common parlance, "spaghetti code".

Instead, have the Fragment notify the Activity that the profile image has changed. Then the activity can handle changing the content of the ImageView.

The commonly recommended way of doing this is to create a pair of interfaces through which the Activity and the Fragment communicate. While this way is recommended a lot, it's probably not the best way (lots of code, and error-prone).

I find that the easiest way is to use a message bus (see Otto, GreenRobot, etc.). The Fragment can put a message on the bus, and the Activity can listen to the bus for that incoming message, and take appropriate action when it arrives. This can be used in both directions, if desired.

Comment: Thank you! Haha yes I am trying to unravel my spaghetti code as we speak.  Hoping with experience and practice my code will be better structured.  I will follow your advice and I like the sound of the Bus idea. There will be a lot of updating of UIs within this app and that sounds like it will be perfect.  Again thanks for your time!